# App crashes when using realm and listener

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, bottom-sheet

I'm currently running into an annoying issue where I don't know if it's a bug or if I've implemented something wrong. This causes my app to crash sporadically with no apparent error message. I've been searching on Stackoverflow and other pages but so far no solution. The error it self to long to post, so I post the first lines if its not a problem.

Error Message:

```
2021-11-06 21:19:55.269 31533-31533/com.example.test A/ple.test: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewLocalRef called with pending exception java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    java_vm_ext.cc:577] (Throwable with no stack trace)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577] 
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]     in call to NewLocalRef
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]     from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)

2021-11-06 21:19:55.455 31533-31533/com.example.test A/ple.test: runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:655] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
    runtime.cc:655] All threads:
    runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (40):
    runtime.cc:655] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
…
```

I've been troubleshooting all day today to get to the point that problem lies within BottomSheetDialogFragment and RealmDB. So when I start the function "updateContactChat" everything works fine, no errors. As soon as I open the same BottomSheetDialogFragment again and start the function "updateContactChat" the app crashes completely with the above error.

The is the code.

```
 class ChatAdd : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private val appRealm = Realm.getInstance(General.secureDB())
    private var binding: FragmentChatsAddBinding? = null
    
    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    
        binding = FragmentChatsAddBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    
    
        return binding!!.root
    }
    
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(requireView().parent as View).apply {
            state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }
    
    
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        R.style.DialogAnimation.also { dialog!!.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = it }
    
        binding!!.contactListContainer.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        binding!!.contactListContainer.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding!!.contactListContainer.addItemDecoration(ContactsList.ItemDecoration())
    
        showList()
    }
    
    
    private fun showList() {
    
        var contacts: RealmResults<SchemeContacts>? = null
    
        binding!!.contactListContainer.adapter = ContactsAdapter(contacts, true, object :
            ContactsAdapter.ContactItemClickListener {
            override fun onClick(contact: SchemeContacts?) {
    
                contact?.contact_id?.let {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        try {
                            updateContactChat(it)
                        }catch(e:Exception){
                            Log.d("log", "catch error: "+e)
                        }
                    }
                }
    
            }
        })
    
    }
    
    
    private fun updateContactChat(contactId: String) {
    
        val updateRealm = Realm.getInstance(General.secureDB())
    
        updateRealm.executeTransaction { bgRealm ->
    
            val user =
                bgRealm.where<SchemeContacts>().equalTo("contact_id", contactId).findFirst()!!
            user.contact_chat = true
            user.contact_chatupdated = LocalDateTime.now().toString()
            user.contact_chatnew = 0
            user.contact_chatstatus = 0
    
        }
    
        updateRealm.close()
        dialog!!.dismiss()
    
    }
    
    
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        appRealm.close()
        binding = null
    }
}
```

I have tried several solutions also with Realm DB but to no avail unfortunately.
I hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE:**

I had a changelistener which triggers when changes are made in the database. This code was in my Parent Fragment and not in my Bottomsheet fragment. So when I selected a contact the database gets updated which triggers the listener in the Parent Fragment(and you will be sent to that particular contactFragment). This was the code for the listener.

```
 fun runListener(){
contacts?.addChangeListener(OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener { contacts, changeSet ->
                if (contacts.size > 0) {
                    binding!!.notfound.root.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    binding!!.notfound.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
    })
}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    binding = null
    appRealm.close()
}
```

So the first time nothing happens because the binding exist and it will run without errors and Android will run "onDestroy" which binding and db are getting closed/nulled. Because I never closed the listener this will keep continue listening.
When I repeat my actions and start a new listener both Listeners are getting called. The first Listener will look for the "binding" which does not exist because I "nulled" it when Android destroyed the fragment at the first time. So thats why I get a Null Exception. The binding of the first listener does not exist anymore.

After changing the code to this, everything worked fine without crashes or errors:

```
fun runListener(){
        
contacts?.addChangeListener(OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener { 
  contacts, changeSet ->
    try {
            if(binding != null) {
                if (contacts.size > 0) {
                    binding!!.notfound.root.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    binding!!.notfound.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
    }catch(e:Exception){
      Log.d("error","Try Catch error: "+e.toString())
    }
  })
}
      
        
override fun onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy()
  if(contacts != null){
        contacts!!.removeAllChangeListeners()
  }
  binding = null
  appRealm.close()
}
```

I hope it's clear and it's really a long beginner's mistake and a very important lesson. Close everything you start.

Comment: The error is being thrown because you're accessing a var that is NULL (see the error). You should add a breakpoint to your code and step through it on line at a time inspecting the vars and code flow along the way. When you find something it not right, update your question as to the line the error occurred on. Right off the bat, I would guess this `General.secureDB()` is suspect but... that's just a guess. Trubleshoot and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a Realm listener on the parent fragment which is bound to an element. It apparently gets nulled which causes the error.

Comment: It would be really helpful for the future readers if you add the fixed code as well and explain in details what has been done.

Comment: @Ruli you are right, I updated the topic and added my solution. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

> Am not sure I understand your question, if the crash happens when bottomSheet is dismissed ensure you close every realm transaction once done by calling`real.close()`

Comment: I have updated my topic and the answer to my problem.